# Unable to set 00:00 on change time from bootstrap timepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I Used Bootstrap timepicker of http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/ site. My code is below:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({

showMeridian: false,
defaultTime:value,
disableFocus: true

});
```

All time is displaying properly in the textbox. But when I click on the field to try to change the time and try to set 00:00 then that value didnot show on the textbox.Is there a setting I need to adjust to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: There is a [pull-request](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/pull/339/files) now, with this it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same tool, it works pretty well.
When I change time (as Screen user), to 0:00, then it Shows 00:00.

Try without "defaultTime:value".

My config:

```
$('#ZeitStart').timepicker({
                    minuteStep: 1,
                    showSeconds: false,
                    showMeridian: false
});
```